# Is it possible to disable MacBook trackpad under Windows 7?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macbook-pro

Is it possible to disable trackpad when running Windows 7 on Macbook Air/Pro? Anyone with this setup can confirm that it's possible?

(I don't use this setup yet, I'm just thinking about it, and want to make sure it supports my needs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it in System -> Hardware as far as I remember.

Comment: I was looking for simple checkbox rather than disabling device in hardware list, but that will also work I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Well there's also the Touchpad settings in Control Panel -> Mouse but I'm not sure if you can perma-disable it there. Might be worth a look.

Comment: that's why I asked here ;-) I don't use this setup yet, so I cannot look myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm too much of an Apple nerd to remember the Windows control panels with anything other than abject horror ;)

Answer (score 6):

Well, good news. I figured out how to stop that annoying errant cursor from suddenly moving my typing to an unintended place.

Ignore all you have read above.

On the Start bar at the bottom on your screen, far right find the Boot Camp icon.
Click it
See "Boot Camp Control Panel..."
Click it
Click Yes to allowing to proceed
See at the top tabs "Trackpad"
Click it
unclick Tap To Click
click OK

Voila!

Now touching the track pad won't move the cursor...only pressing down to "click" it will.

Comment: This gotta be the accepted answer.. maybe it was not avaliable when the question came up, but from now on THIS ONE ROCKS.....

Answer (score 4):

Go to Device Manager, expand Human Interface Devices, find the Apple Multi-touch device, right click it, choose disable.  Done!

Comment: Perfect and simple answer

Answer (score 2):

Start > Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Apple Keyboard/Trackpad > Right click, Properties > Hardware > HID- Compliant mouse, MICE and OT.. > Properties > Anable/Disable//

You must disable the both Mice and ot.. becouse one is for the click's and one is for the mouse movement.

Greetings,
Georgi.

[image: DisableTrackpad]
[image: DisableTrackpad]
[image: DisableTrackpad]

Answer (score 1):

Via Control Panel you can't. Although you can disable the "touch click", and that way the click is made by "clicking" the trackpad, thus reducing accidental clicking.
There are 3rd-party tools for disabling it easily, or when a mouse is connected, but the few I tried (Trackpad++ and TrackpadMagic) didn't work for me (MBA Mid2011 + Win7)

Comment: How do I disable "touch click"? That's the stuff that makes the cursor jump while I'm typing. And I hate hate hate it. Actually I just found this Touchpad++ driver. Gonna try it next: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2436935?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Disable the first option just like the example:[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it in bootcamp control panel.